# Order by reversed foreign key attribute in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following Django models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...
    region = models.CharField(...)
    group = models.ForeignKey(CityGroup, null=True)

class CityGroup(models.Model):
    ...
```

The Cities in a CityGroup all have the same region. Is it possible to order the CityGroups by the region of its Cities? (Preferably with only one query). I want to avoid moving the region field to CityGroup.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that

```
query = CityGroup.objects.all().order_by('city__region')
```

Comment: Possibly `city__region__name` or some other field on the `region` model, I think the above would order by the `region` pk, but the OP didn't actually specify.

Comment: Above `region` is a `CharField`. But you're right, if it would be a foreign key.

Comment: Oh, right. I should read more closely. Hmm, I wonder if the above actually works given that a `CityGroup` has multiple `city` relations - even if they're all in the same region, the DBM has no way to know or enforce that. Hazards of denormalization I guess.

Comment: It does not really work the way I wanted. The query was accepted by Django but it resulted in duplicates of CityGroups. Not really sure how Django interprets this type of query (when a CityGroup has multiple cities)?

Comment: Couldn't you query `City` and add a `.distinct("group")` on there to get only the unique groups?